# How to create a ReloadRow animation

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I created this function to reload a single row of the tableView after a button is tapped.

```
@IBAction func reloadCell(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let index = IndexPath(row: sender.tag, section: 0)
    self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [index], with: .none)
}
```

But I would like an animation to reload the row that moves the row from right to left so as to make it clear that the line has been reloaded. How can I do this?

Comment: Any reason you didn't look at the documentation for the `reloadRows(at:with:)` method and the possible values for the `with:` parameter before posting this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use either the `right` or `left` `UITableViewRowAnimation`:

```
tableView.reloadRows(at: [index], with: .right)
```

or

```
tableView.reloadRows(at: [index], with: .left)
```

The available animations can be seen in [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewrowanimation).